# Infopath 2013: Add an action rule to a submit button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, infopath-rules

I'm trying to create submit buttons that also change a field to a value. For example, in a form, department A, B and C have to input information and then submit it but I also need each submit button to change a field to a value so a workflow can continue running. How could I manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Insert a button and select it
- click the Control Tools > Properties ribbon
- on the very left, in the Action drop-down, select "Rules", not "Submit"
- add an action rule to the button to change the field you want to change
- add an action rule to the button to submit data and another action to close the form

You could put all these actions into the same rule, but separating them into field change rules and submit/close rule makes things more manageable, especially in complex scenarios.